# Webpack Highcharts Plugin IIFE

Tags: javascript, highcharts, webpack-2

Currently using [Highcharts from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) and I'm using expose-loader and script loader to configure [highcharts-rounded-corners](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/5/Rounded-Corners) in the following way.

The rounded-corners plugin is an iife that expect a global Highcharts object to exist. Therefore I expose it using expose-loader and then execute the script with script-loader.

While this method works I was wondering if there is a better solution than this one?

```
//Configure Highcharts
require("expose-loader?Highcharts!highcharts");
require("script-loader!../../vendor/highcharts/plugins/rounded-corners-master/rounded-corners.min.js");
```

Comment: Maybe if you could define what should be improved then you could get more replies / answers.

Answer (score 0):

try to require highcharts like this

```
window.Highcharts = require('highcharts');
require('highcharts-exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
```